# Updating an array in a document when filtering on multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

(Currently on mongo 3.2.13)

My document sort of looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').insertMany(
[
{
    Name: "Two",
    "Stores": [
        {
          StoreName: "PayMore",
          StoreId: 123
        },
    ]
    Orders: {
        Items: [
        {
            ItemName: "A",
            Properties: {
                Color: "Red",
                Price: 0.99
            }
        },
        {
            ItemName: "B",
            Properties: {
                Color: "Yellow",
                Price: 0.69
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
]
)
```

Now, as things are wont to do, the price of "B" is going to go up, but only when it's carried by store 123.

So I try to do this:

```
db.getCollection('test').bulkWrite(
[
{
    updateOne: {
        filter:
        // query 
    {
        Name: "Two",
        "Stores.StoreId": 123,
        "Orders.Items.ItemName": "B"
    },
    update:
    {
        $set: {
            "Orders.Items.$.Properties.Price": 0.78
        }
    },
    options:
    {
        "multi" : false,
        "upsert" : false
    }
}
}
]
);
```

something weird happens. Even though I'm trying to match on item "B", it's actually item "A" that is getting updated. Note that if I don't match on stores, then I get item "B" updated as desired, but I may end up inadvertently changing stuff for Bs that are not associated with store 123, and we don't want that.

A way to continue filtering on both arrays but only update the one would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-array-filters) to be more explicit about what to apply your update:

```
{
    updateOne: {
        filter:
        // query 
    {
        Name: "Two",
        "Stores.StoreId": 123,
        "Orders.Items.ItemName": "B"
    },
    update:
    {
        $set: {
            "Orders.Items.$[itemFilter].Properties.Price": 0.78
        }
    },
    options:{
        "multi" : false,
        "upsert" : false,
        "arrayFilters":[{"itemFilter.itemName":"B"}]
    }
}
```